# Some odd behavior: Move all files in a folder to another location

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to move all files in a folder (Desktop) to another but only HALF of the files end up being moved, howcome?
Here is my code:

```
WCHAR DesktopPath[MAX_PATH];
pExpandEnvironmentStringsW(L"%userprofile%\\Desktop\\", DesktopPath, MAX_PATH);

WCHAR DesktopFiles[MAX_PATH];
lstrcpyW(DesktopFiles, DesktopPath);
lstrcatW(DesktopFiles, L"DesktopFiles\\");
CreateDirectory(DesktopFiles, NULL);

WCHAR search_path[200];
wsprintf(search_path, L"%s/*.*", DesktopPath);
WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
HANDLE hFind = ::FindFirstFile(search_path, &fd);
if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    do {

            WCHAR filepath[MAX_PATH];
            lstrcpyW(filepath, DesktopPath);
            lstrcatW(filepath, fd.cFileName);

            WCHAR newpath[MAX_PATH];
            lstrcpyW(newpath, DesktopFiles);
            lstrcatW(newpath, fd.cFileName);

            MoveFile(filepath, newpath);
    } while (::FindNextFile(hFind, &fd));
    ::FindClose(hFind);
}
```

Comment: I expect that the problem is caused by you modifying the state of the directory whilst iterating over it. It would make far more sense to use `SHFileOperation` or `IFileOperation`. But if you simply insist of doing all the hard work yourself, build a list of the files first, and then move them.

Comment: Maybe because the movement of the file caused the handle `hFind` to go awry since the file doesn't exist?  Also, have you considered just using the functions in [shlwapi.lib](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to move files?

Comment: I updated my code, @DavidHeffernan. It is still not working this way.

Comment: Please stop changing the question. You already have an answer to it.

Comment: Relying on the env vars to obtain special folder locations is risky. In real code you'd want to use the known folder API.

Answer (score 2):

There's a warning in the Windows API about use of FindFirstFile/FindNextFile loop about changing the directory in the loop. Make a list, then move the files in another loop. [Incidentally delete is explicitly defined to work so we should be surprised move isn't. And as we see below, that's not what's really going on.]

Having now read the intermediate edit, he has fallen into an interesting mistake. The source directory is the desktop. It moved all of his files on the desktop, and didn't look at the all users desktop, which is another directory. (In fact enough information is present in the original question to see this, but not enough to see that he was expecting it to apply to the all users desktop.) This isn't going to work so well because the target directory doesn't exist on the all users desktop. While he could create it, this just ends up with two of them visible, and merging arbitrary directories as folder views is too advanced a topic.

Comment: Please don't hold us to ransom and force us to attempt to debug code that we cannot see. We can tell you what is wrong with your code. And that's it. You then need to step up and fix your code. Don't be a help vampire.

Comment: What do you mean? I updated my code? Can't see?? step up and Debug??? It compiles successfully it is just exhibiting weird behavior THATS WHY IM HERE DONT YOU THINK I TRIED TO DEBUG IT. What is your problem I thought this is what this website is for.

Comment: No, we are not here to debug a constantly changing piece of code. I reverted the question to its original form since your edit invalidates everything that is here. Since you are new here, you don't yet understand our conventions. Please spend some time at the [help]. Why don't you do some debugging? I'm guessing you don't know how to yet, and this is the perfect opportunity for you to learn. Good luck.

Comment: No, I'm here because I already tried to do some debugging and couldn't find the problem. So, I am here, on stackoverflow, for the very reason it was created. Stop trying to be smart, and go somewhere else.

Comment: If you don't like our customs, then you can try to persuade us to change them on meta. Until then it's going to be most productive for you to fit in.

Comment: You need some help man. I am utilizing this website just fine. I already tried to do some debugging and couldn't find the error and that's why I'm here. "Constantly changing" -- I changed it once -- not a big deal. Just what do you think I'm doing wrong?? Explain yourself.

Comment: Do some better debugging. Have your program write out `filepath` and `newpath` at the line where you call `MoveFile`. Then try to explain the output that you observe.

Comment: Okay, just as my first observation, there appears to be nothing wrong. I will try to use IFIleOperation instead.

Comment: I still don't believe it deserves a downvote though.